# Using new created folder with timestamps

Tags: c#

I am new to c#, I have made a function which creates a new folder with a time stamp everytime the console is run.

```
string newfolder = @"d:\Denby_Screenshots" + DateTime.Now.ToString(" yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-fff");
        if (!Directory.Exists(newfolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newfolder);
            Console.WriteLine("Screenshot folder has been created");
        }
```

I then would like this to be down to allow the screenshots to be saved into this newly created file.

```
static private Test_Criteria Block_Two(IWebDriver driver, Screenshot screenshot, string newfolder)
    {
        {
        screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
      screenshot.SaveAsFile("d:\\ScreenShot.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

But for the life of me I am not sure how to do this would anyone be able to advise or have any good screenshots for me to be able to work from.
Thanks

Comment: What behavior are you seeing, and what are you expecting?

Comment: You have a string with the name of your folder, so just use that. Append the filename and you're good to go. You could even use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx).

Comment: The behaviour which I am seeing is an Exception when I try to add the newfolder variable into the path which the folder has been created in. I am trying to make the screen shots which are being taken from the code below to be added in to the most recent file created.

Comment: What is the scope of `newfolder`? This directory path needs to be stored in a static field from what I understand of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing these two steps in one console context. Then simply, return newly created folder name to the calling function. And use that folder name (as string) to save files into.

Something like this:

`SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(returnedFolderName, suggestedFileName).....`

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
screenshot.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(newFolder,"screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

And reconsider your folder structure, it would be extremely annoying to have a zillion folders in your root folder with just one file in each.

A better approach would be

```
newFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures, "Screenshots",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

And the target file name:

```
Path.Combine(newFolder, "Screenshot "+DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss-fff")+".png");
```